# AES encryption with Crypto and decryption with CryptoJS returns empty string

Tags: node.js, react-native, cryptography, aes, cryptojs

My back-end encrypts a string using `Crypto` from node.js.

On the client side I want to decrypt the string using `CryptoJS`. However, I always get an empty string as result.

**Encryption (Crypto):**

```
function encrypt(value) {
  const cipher = crypto.createCipher('aes-256-ctr', 'SECRET_STRING');
  let crypted = cipher.update(value,'utf8','hex');
  crypted += cipher.final('hex');
  return crypted;
}
```

**Decryption (CryptoJS):**

```
const decrypt = (value) => {
  const bytes = CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse(value);
  const decrypted = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(
    bytes,
    'SECRET_STRING',
    { 
       mode: CryptoJS.mode.ECB, 
       padding: CryptoJS.pad.NoPadding
    },
  );
  return decrypted.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8);
};
```

This returns an empty string. What do I misunderstand and what am I doing wrong?

Comment: There is at least one problem here.

 - Crypto uses `aes-256-ctr` that is AES with 256-bit key with CTR mode which doesn't require padding.
 - CryptoJS, however, uses CBC mode by [default][1]. You should define the CTR mode

Comment: @kelalaka You are right, I changed the OP since I already editted my code. My guess is that my 'key' isn't right? and I'm not suren what an 'iv' is.

Comment: The modes are still incompatible. In CryptoJS you need to say `CryptoJS.mode.CTR`. But what is your aim? ECB is insecure, CTR has vulnerabilities. You should you authenticated encryption as AES-GCM or chacha20-poly1305.